# Secure reverse UltraVNC connection to bypass firewall

Tags: windows-7, firewall, vnc, ultravnc

My clients and service run on mostly Windows 7.

I need help setting up a secure reverse connection with UltraVNC between me and a client.(Me=Viewer, Client=Server)

Here is my situation:

I want to reverse connect from the client (server) to me (viewer) but I think the client's firewall blocks *outgoing* connections, therefore the Server on the client's PC can't connect to my viewer.

Note: I don't have access to the client's firewall so I was hoping to bypass the firewall with a secure connection (like the dsm plugin maybe?) instead of just using an unsecured connection.

I have already forwarded the necessary ports on my router since the client is connecting to me and not the other way around.

Can I bypass the client's firewall using a secure connection? if so, I am having trouble getting the right method to set it up using reverse connections.

I have done my research regarding a secure UVNC connection but had no luck so far with reverse connections.

PS. My setup works with the rest of my clients with a normal unsecured connection.
A few of my client's have restrictive firewalls, which seems ot be blocking the server reverse connecting out. I am hoping a secure connection could bypass the restrictions.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

Here you have the solution
http://www.uvnc.com/products/pchelpware.html

It's free!

Comment: Will it run on windows 7?

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Requirements: "Windows 95, 98, ME, 2000, 2003, XP, Vista"